# Wordpress wp_ajax public url?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I would like to do an ajax request in my theme.

If I am login to the Back Office, the request does, but if I'm not logged in, the returns is null... What's the solution please ?

In my view :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://www.mysite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
  data: $('#EventForm').serialize()+'&action=event_form',
  success: function(response){
    if(response == 1){
      alert('ok');
    } else {
      alert('no ok');
  }
});
```

In the functions.php (works only if I am log in back Office)

```
add_action('wp_ajax_event_form', 'ajax_event_form');
function ajax_event_form(){
  global $wpdb; 
  ...
  echo true;
  die;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side): `wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)` executes for users that are not logged in. So, if you want it to fire on the front-end for both visitors and logged-in users, you can do this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a plugin and add this:

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name:ajax
 */
function my_ajax_callback_function() {
    echo "hiii";
    print_r($_POST);
    exit();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action_name', 'my_ajax_callback_function' );    
// If called from admin panel
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action_name', 'my_ajax_callback_function' );
```

Create a js and add this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: "my_action_name","name":"hithin","age":"27"
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: you could also do `$(function(){ ... })` instead of the double-wrapping

Comment: how come the JS file has this? <?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>

Answer (score 3):

The ajax request in WordPress works by classifying user in two categories

1) User with login privilege.
2) User without login privileges.

So if you are logged in(even as a subscriber) your ajax function will be triggered i.e.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_event_form', 'ajax_event_form');
```

this will call 'ajax_event_form' function.

To make this work for non-logged in users you will have to write this below your ajax action

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_event_form', 'ajax_event_form');
```

So your code will be like:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_event_form', 'ajax_event_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_event_form', 'ajax_event_form');
function ajax_event_form(){
  global $wpdb; 
  ...
  echo true;
  die;
}
```